# I need advice about Magento hosting

Tags: magento

Can someone propose a good hosting solution for Magento with this requirements:

I have a store in Magento with more than 6000 SKUs.
Configurable products are not so many but I have a lot of attributes. Like mostly 3 attributes for each configurable. 
One configurable can have 1000 associated products.

I am struggling with a provider that gives me only problems. 
This is the plan I have SERVER VPS1 http://www.clausweb.ro/pachet_vps.php. Nothing works well there so far.

I've talked with Hostgator support and they proposed me Standard Dedicated Server but I find it very expensive.

Does Magento really needs so many resources?
Should I change to Shopify?

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I am a little desperate. So far I pay for a solution that does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the appropriate forum to ask for these types of questions.  To help you though, I highly recommend the guys [MageMojo](http://magemojo.com/) for Magento optimized hosting.